# Calculate the Surface Area

Tags: integration

Having trouble finding the surface area given:
Bounded by: $x=0, x=4, z=0, z=1$
Surface: $y=4x-z^2$

I've tried trigonometric substitutions, and logarithmic substitutions, but I can't seem to solve this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in order to find the surface area, we have to solve the double integral $$\int \int \sqrt{(f_x)^2 + (f_z)^2 + 1} dx dz$$
 Now if we substitute in the partial derivatives and put in the bounds, we get 
$$\int_0^1\int_0^4\sqrt{(4)^2 + (-2z)^2 + 1} dxdz$$
$$4\int_0^1\sqrt{4z^2+17} dz$$
This integral is much easier to solve. We now perform a trig sub.
$$z=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{17}\sinh(u)$$
$$dz=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{17}\cosh(u)du$$
$$4\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{17}}}} \sqrt{17\sinh^2(u)+17}(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{17}\cosh(u))du$$
$$34\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{17}}}} \cosh^2(u))du$$
$$17\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{17}}}} \cosh(2u)+1 du$$
$$2\sqrt{21} + 17\sinh^{-1}\frac{2\sqrt{17}}{17}$$
The next time you see an integral of $\sqrt{ax^2+b}$, try substituting a multiple of $\sinh(u)$

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I was stuck at the third step, did not know how to substitute to solve. Kind of obscure substitution, I've never seen a hyperbolic sine used. Thanks again